# CollectionViewのセルに毎回違ったidentifierを持たせる

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

CollectionViewのセルに`cellForItemAtIndexPath`が呼ばれるたび、毎回違ったidentifierを持たせたいのですが、やり方が分かりません。もしくはできないのでしょうか？
例えば最初の画面読み込みで、ある`identifier`を持った再利用可能なセルを30個生成し、次に画面が読み込まれた時は別の`identifier`を持った再利用可能なセルを30個生成するといったようなことです。

```
CalendarCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

`cellForItemAtIndexPath`メソッド内の上記の行で、「`must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`」とエラーが返ってきます。（上記の行の`identifier`には画面が読み込まれるたびに違う文字列が入ります。）しかし`Storyboard`の`Collection Reusable View`の`Identifier`にはあらかじめ指定した一つの文字列しか入れることができないので、`cellForItemAtIndexPath`内の`identifier`と`Collection Reusable View`の`identifier`を一致させることができません。
なので、どうすれば都度都度違った`identifier`を持ったセルを生成することができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: “セルのプロパティIdentifierを変更したい”のでしょうか？あるいは“Identifierが異なるセルを、その都度Collection Viewに配置したい”のでしょうか？

Comment: 画面に表示されている分の30個のセルのidentifierは同じで大丈夫です。次回CollectionViewのセルが描画される時に前回とは違うidentifierを設定したいです。

Comment: なので、“セルのプロパティIdentifierを変更したい”の方になるでしょうか。

Comment: なんの意味があるのかさっぱり理解できないという前提はあるんですが、`UICollectionReusableView`のクラスリファレンス`reuseIdentifier`にあるように、**ReadOnly**のプロパティなので、変更は不可です。

Comment: identifierを変更することは不可能なのですね。
了解しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

下図のようにStoryboardで、Collection ViewのAttributes Inspectorで、**Items**の値を変えれば、CellのIdentifierを複数作ることができます。Itemを2にすると、Collection ViewのCellのプロトタイプが2つになることがわかります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問者さんの意図に添えないまま終わってしまいましたが、私の回答をこのまま削除するのも、もったいない気がするので、「**セルをタップするたびに、セルが入れ替わるプログラム**」のサンプルを掲載して、回答を完結させておこうと思います。（Swiftにて失礼）

Storyboard上で、セルのプロトタイプを7つ作り、`Identifier`をそれぞれ`CellA`、`CellB`、〜、`CellF`、`CellG`とします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`ViewController`のコードを編集します。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    // セルのIdentifierを配列で定数化しておく。
    let identifiers: [String] = ["CellA", "CellB", "CellC", "CellD", "CellE", "CellF", "CellG"]
    // 配列identifiersのなん番目かを示す整数型の変数。
    var num: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Collection ViewのDatasourceとDelegate
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30 // セルの個数は30固定
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // num番目のIdentifierのセルを配置する。
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifiers[num], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // セルをタップするごとにCellA→CellB→〜→CellF→CellG→CellA→CellB→〜と切り替わる。
        num = (num + 1) % 7
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、質問の仕方がよくなかったです。cellForItemAtIndexPathが呼ばれるたび、一つのセルに毎回違ったidentifierを持たせたいということが僕のしたいことでした。あるidentifierを持った再利用可能なセルを30個生成し、次に画面が読み込まれた時は違ったidentifierを持った再利用可能なセルを30個生成したいです。こういうことはできるのでしょうか？なお、質問内容は修正しました。